# Project ID instead of app name displaying in Google Fit permissions panel

Tags: google-fit

Can somebody shed some light on why the project id is displayed instead of the application name on the Google Fit permissions panel in apps?

Screenshot
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtDOB.jpg

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of what you mean?

Comment: Screenshot added to help with clarity.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Android appears to no longer take the name of the app from the app but from the OAuth consent in the Google Cloud Platform "App Name" field at [https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent/edit?project=[app-name]](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent/edit?project=%5Bapp-name%5D).

That field had apparently been auto populated with "project-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" instead of the app name when the field was created by Google.